# How to install ROS diamondback on TrimSlice(Natty)?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, rosinstall, ubuntu-natty, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,
I was browsing this forum for questions like my, but still have no clue what is the best way for me to install ros-diamondback on device called trimslice - trimslice.com. I just got it two days ago, and it has Nvidia Tegra CPU and Ubuntu Natty pre-installed. With this configuration I can not follow howto on [www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Install](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Install). What is the best way from me to install it? Detailed instruction will be highly appreciated since I don't have much experience with linux, however have completed my OS class )). A few cents would be a gold for me. Thanks.
-Roman.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11480/how-to-install-ros-diamondback-on-trimslice(natty)?/) by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-10-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the Trimslice which I believe is an ARM processor, so there are not natty debs available at the moment.  You should be able to follow the Ubuntu [install from source directions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-10-12**:
Thanks a lot. This work out pretty well. Now I'm going to test it.